# Would putting green grapefruit in water help them to not dry out and will they ripen?

Tags: citrus

I have just gathered 5 green grapefruit that fell from my tree today.  I read here that they dry out when waiting for them to ripen. I was wondering if there was a solution like water, maybe water plus sugar or something, that would help them to ripen without drying out.  A couple are green-green. A couple are 3/4 green.

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/63110/67

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I ripen unripe oranges and grapefruits?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/154/how-do-i-ripen-unripe-oranges-and-grapefruits)